# Saving Rss Feed into Database

Tags: iphone

I have one problem, i want to save the rss data coming from xml into local database but it takes from time because it contain images and i also save images in resource path.
so how can i parse and save data at same time? it take lots of time so is there any method that runs on background?

for eg: i will load all data from the xml into an array and display in to tableview after that on background the array will save data in database?

Thank You.

Comment: You have asked 38 questions, so far. Please mark them answered when people have been nice enough to take the time to answer your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` method to run code in a background thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doStuffInBackgroundThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil]
```

If you use the `libxml` framework, as you parse each XML node of interest, once the parse is complete, you can then fire off a selector on a separate thread to add the data to a database or Core Data store.

Take a look at Apple's [XMLPerformance sample project](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/index.html) for more information.